# How to get absolute URI of hyperlink in MS word using OpenXML SDK?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, openxml, office-interop, openxml-sdk

A MS word file contains a link to local files (MS word, excel, visio ...), I used OpenXML to get absolute URI of linking local files. But I only get filename.

Could you give me some advice?

```
  using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docxFile, true))
{
    Body body = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    //-----------------------------------------------
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Hyperlink hLink = body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Hyperlink>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (hLink != null)
    {
        // get hyperlink's relation Id (where path stores)
        string relationId = hLink.Id;
        if (relationId != string.Empty)
        {
            // get current relation
            HyperlinkRelationship hr = document.MainDocumentPart.HyperlinkRelationships.Where(a => a.Id == relationId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (hr != null)
            { 
                string path = hr.Uri.AbsolutePath; //exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use hr.Uri.ToString() method to get the path

According to MSDN: "The AbsolutePath property contains the path information that the server uses to resolve requests for information."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you for giving advice. I tried hr.Uri.ToString(), but I only get filename instead fullpath. And attribute isAbsoluteUri is false.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fJfGN_G72yQjJqWUJtcjRaMUE/view?usp=drivesdk